# Can MySQL replace multiple characters?

Tags: mysql, sql, string, replace

I'm trying to replace a bunch of characters in a MySQL field. I know the REPLACE function but that only replaces one string at a time. I can't see any appropriate functions [in the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html).

Can I replace or delete multiple strings at once? For example I need to replace spaces with dashes and remove other punctuation.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

You can chain REPLACE functions:

```
select replace(replace('hello world','world','earth'),'hello','hi')
```

This will print `hi earth`.

You can even use subqueries to replace multiple strings!

```
select replace(london_english,'hello','hi') as warwickshire_english
from (
    select replace('hello world','world','earth') as london_english
) sub
```

Or use a JOIN to replace them:

```
select group_concat(newword separator ' ')
from (
    select 'hello' as oldword
    union all
    select 'world'
) orig
inner join (
    select 'hello' as oldword, 'hi' as newword
    union all
    select 'world', 'earth'
) trans on orig.oldword = trans.oldword
```

I'll leave translation using common table expressions as an exercise for the reader ;)

Comment: @Zak: eh... right, you actually read the query?  I'll edit it ;)

Comment: Sorry, meant to put in the question I've been using nested REPLACEs. I was hoping for something similar to PHP's `str_replace` function, but I guess it doesn't exist.

Comment: Andomar: MySQL doesn't support the `WITH` clause; no one should be providing a CTE equivalent query...

Comment: Chaining REPLACE can lead to a problem of replacing things that you have already replaced, so if you do REPLACE(REPLACE(1234, 1, 4), 4, 1), you won't get 4231 as expected; you'll get 1231 instead, so chaining replaces is not an exact substitute for list replacements.  There needs to be a better solution.

Answer (score 11):

[`REPLACE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#idm140269995815216) does a good simple job of replacing  characters or phrases everywhere they appear in a string. But when cleansing punctuation you may need to look for patterns - e.g. a sequence of whitespace or characters in the middle of a word or after a full stop. If that's the case, a regular expression replace function would be much more powerful.

---

**UPDATE:** If using MySQL version 8+, a [`REGEXP_REPLACE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-replace) function is provided and can be invoked as follows:

```
SELECT txt,
       REGEXP_REPLACE(REPLACE(txt, ' ', '-'),
                      '[^a-zA-Z0-9-]+',
                      '') AS `reg_replaced`
FROM test;
```

See [this DB Fiddle online demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9uc3facySsER5sNeThd1gi/0).

---

**PREVIOUS ANSWER - *only read on if using a version of MySQL before version 8*:** .

The bad news is [MySQL doesn't provide such a thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826) but the good news is it's possible to provide a workaround - see [this blog post](http://stevettt.blogspot.co.uk/2018/02/a-mysql-regular-expression-replace.html).

> Can I replace or delete multiple strings at once? For example I need
> to replace spaces with dashes and remove other punctuation.

The above can be achieved with a combination of the regular expression replacer and the standard `REPLACE` function. It can be seen in action in [this online Rextester demo](http://rextester.com/TEO73043).

**SQL *(excluding the function code for brevity)*:**

```
SELECT txt,
       reg_replace(REPLACE(txt, ' ', '-'),
                   '[^a-zA-Z0-9-]+',
                   '',
                   TRUE,
                   0,
                   0
                   ) AS `reg_replaced`
FROM test;
```

Answer (score 11):

```
CREATE FUNCTION IF NOT EXISTS num_as_word (name TEXT) RETURNS TEXT RETURN
(
    SELECT 
        REPLACE(
            REPLACE(
                REPLACE(
                    REPLACE(
                        REPLACE(
                            REPLACE(                            
                                REPLACE(
                                    REPLACE(                            
                                        REPLACE(IFNULL(name, ''), 
                                            '1', 'one'), 
                                            '2', 'two'), 
                                            '3', 'three'), 
                                            '4', 'four'), 
                                            '5', 'five'), 
                                            '6', 'six'), 
                                            '7', 'seven'),                                                          
                                            '8', 'eight'),
                                            '9', 'nine')
);
```

Comment: ahh, nothing quite like making something inherently ugly look beautiful.

Comment: If only there was a `REPLACE(input, search1, replace1, ..., searchN, replaceN)`. But this here is as good as we can get.

Answer (score 10):

Cascading is the only simple and straight-forward solution to mysql for multiple character replacement.

```
UPDATE table1 
SET column1 = replace(replace(REPLACE(column1, '\r\n', ''), '<br />',''), '<\r>','')
```

Comment: As observed in another answer, **this might not work**. Chain-replacing A B C with C D E, for example, will replace A with C, *and then replace C with E*, so that "HAL" will not become "HCL" but "HEL".

Answer (score 8):

I've been using [lib_mysqludf_preg](https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_preg) for this which allows you to:

> Use PCRE regular expressions directly in MySQL

With this library installed you could do something like this:

```
SELECT preg_replace('/(\\.|com|www)/','','www.example.com');
```

Which would give you:

```
example
```

Answer (score 7):

on php

```
$dataToReplace = [1 => 'one', 2 => 'two', 3 => 'three'];
$sqlReplace = '';
foreach ($dataToReplace as $key => $val) {
    $sqlReplace = 'REPLACE(' . ($sqlReplace ? $sqlReplace : 'replace_field') . ', "' . $key . '", "' . $val . '")';
}
echo $sqlReplace;
```

result

```
REPLACE(
    REPLACE(
        REPLACE(replace_field, "1", "one"),
    "2", "two"),
"3", "three");
```

Comment: If you want an empty string with no replacements, this would be fine, but I think initiating the `$sqlReplace = 'replace_field';` covers more cases and is more easily readable.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **MySQL Version 8+** then below is the built-in function that might help you better.

| String | Replace | Output |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `w"w\'w. ex%a&m:p l–e.c)o(m` | `"'%&:)(–` | **[www.example.com](http://www.example.com)** |

**MySQL Query:**

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('`w"w\'w.    ex%a&m:p     l–e.c)o(m`', '[("\'%[:blank:]&:–)]', '');
```

#### Almost for all bugging characters-

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(column, '[\("\'%[[:blank:]]&:–,#$@!;\\[\\]\)<>\?\*\^]+','')
```

## Real-life scenario.

I had to update all the files name which has been saved in 'demo' with special characters.

```sql
SELECT * FROM demo;
```

```
| uri                                                                          |
|------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| private://webform/applicant_details/129/offers   upload  winners .png        |
| private://webform/applicant_details/129/student : class & teacher data.pdf   |
| private://webform/applicant_details/130/tax---user's---data__upload.pdf      |
| private://webform/applicant_details/130/Applicant Details _ report_0_2.pdf   |
| private://webform/applicant_details/131/india&asia%population  huge.pdf      |
```

### Test Case -

The table has multiple rows with special characters in the file name.

### Advice:

To remove all the special characters from the file name and use a-z, A-Z, 0-9, dot and underscore with a lower file name.

### Expected result is:

```
| uri                                                                          |
|------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| private://webform/applicant_details/129/offers_upload_winners_.png           |
| private://webform/applicant_details/129/student_class_teacher_data.pdf       |
| private://webform/applicant_details/130/tax_user_s_data_upload.pdf           |
| private://webform/applicant_details/130/applicant_details_report_0_2.pdf     |
| private://webform/applicant_details/131/india_asia_population_huge.pdf       |
```

#### Okay, let's plan step by step

```
1st  - let's find the file name
2nd  - run all the find replace on that file name part only
3rd  - replace the new file name with an old one
```

## How can we do this?

**Let's break down the whole action in chunks for a better understanding.**

***Below function will extract the file name only from the full path e.g. "Applicant Details _ report_0_2.pdf"***

```sql
SELECT                      -- MySQL SELECT statement
  SUBSTRING_INDEX           -- MySQL built-in function
  (                         -- Function start Parentheses
    uri,                    -- my table column
    '/',                    -- delimiter (the last / in full path; left to right ->)
    -1                      -- start from the last and find the 1st one (from right to left <-)
    )                       -- Function end Parentheses
from                        -- MySQL FROM statement
  demo;                     -- My table name
```

#### #1 Query result

```
| uri                                |
|------------------------------------|
| offers   upload  winners .png      |
| student : class & teacher data.pdf |
| tax---user's---data__upload.pdf    |
| Applicant Details _ report_0_2.pdf |
| india&asia%population  huge.pdf    |
```

***Now we have to find and replace within the generated file name result.***

```sql
SELECT 
  REGEXP_REPLACE(                       -- MySQL REGEXP_REPLACE built-in function   (string, pattern, replace)
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(uri, '/', -1),      -- File name only
    '[^a-zA-Z0-9_.]+',                  -- Find everything which is not a-z, A-Z, 0-9, . or _.
    '_'                                 -- Replace with _
  ) AS uri                              -- Give a alias column name for whole result
from 
  demo;
```

#### #2 Query result

```
| uri                                |
|------------------------------------|
| offers_upload_winners_.png         |
| student_class_teacher_data.pdf     |
| tax_user_s_data__upload.pdf        |
| Applicant_Details___report_0_2.pdf |
| india_asia_population_huge.pdf     |
```

***FYI - Last '+' in the pattern is for repetitive words like ---- or multiple spaces '    ', Notice the result without '+' in the below regex pattern.***

```sql
SELECT 
  REGEXP_REPLACE(                       -- MySQL REGEXP_REPLACE built-in function   (string, pattern, replace)
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(uri, '/', -1),      -- File name only
    '[^a-zA-Z0-9_.]',                   -- Find everything which is not a-z, A-Z, 0-9, . or _.
    '_'                                 -- Replace with _
  ) AS uri                              -- Give a alias column name for whole result
from 
  demo;
```

#### #3 Query result

```
| uri                                |
|------------------------------------|
| offers___upload__winners_.png      |
| student___class___teacher_data.pdf |
| tax___user_s___data__upload.pdf    |
| Applicant_Details___report_0_2.pdf |
| india_asia_population__huge.pdf    |
```

Now, we have a file name without special characters (. and _ allowed). But the problem is file name still has Capital letters and also has multiple underscores.

**Let's lower the file name first.**

```sql
SELECT 
  LOWER(
    REGEXP_REPLACE(
      SUBSTRING_INDEX(uri, '/', -1), 
      '[^a-zA-Z0-9_.]', 
      '_'
    )
  ) AS uri 
from 
  demo;
```

#### #4 Query result

```
| uri                                |
|------------------------------------|
| offers_upload_winners_.png         |
| student_class_teacher_data.pdf     |
| tax_user_s_data__upload.pdf        |
| applicant_details___report_0_2.pdf |
| india_asia_population_huge.pdf     |
```

Now everything is in lower case but underscores are still there. So we will wrap the whole REGEX.. with one more REGEX..

```sql
SELECT 
  LOWER(
    REGEXP_REPLACE(                     -- this wrapper will solve the multiple underscores issue
      REGEXP_REPLACE(
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(uri, '/', -1), 
        '[^a-zA-Z0-9_.]+', 
        '_'
      ), 
      '[_]+',                           -- if 1st regex action has multiple __ then find it
      '_'                               -- and replace them with single _
    )
  ) AS uri 
from 
  demo;
```

#### #5 Query result

```
| uri                              |
|----------------------------------|
| offers_upload_winners_.png       |
| student_class_teacher_data.pdf   |
| tax_user_s_data_upload.pdf       |
| applicant_details_report_0_2.pdf |
| india_asia_population_huge.pdf   |
```

## Congratulations! we have found what we were looking for. Now UPDATE TIME! Yeah!!

```sql
UPDATE                                      -- run a MySQL UPDATE statement
  demo                                      -- tell MySQL to which table you want to update
SET                                         -- put SET statement to set the updated values in desire column 
  uri = REPLACE(                            -- tell MySQL to which column you want to update,
                                            -- I am also putting REPLACE function to replace existing values with new one
                                            -- REPLACE (string, replace, with-this)
    uri,                                    -- my column to replace 
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(uri, '/', -1),          -- my file name part "Applicant Details _ report_0_2.pdf"
                                            -- without doing any action
    LOWER(                                  -- "applicant_details_report_0_2.pdf"
      REGEXP_REPLACE(                       -- "Applicant_Details_report_0_2.pdf"
        REGEXP_REPLACE(                     -- "Applicant_Details___report_0_2.pdf"
          SUBSTRING_INDEX(uri, '/', -1),    -- "Applicant Details _ report_0_2.pdf"
          '[^a-zA-Z0-9_.]+', 
          '_'
        ), 
        '[_]+', 
        '_'
      )
    )
  );
```

And after and UPDATE Query, result would be like this.

```
| uri                                                                      |
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| private://webform/applicant_details/152/offers_upload_winners_.png       |
| private://webform/applicant_details/153/student_class_teacher_data.pdf   |
| private://webform/applicant_details/153/tax_user_s_data_upload.pdf       |
| private://webform/applicant_details/154/applicant_details_report_0_2.pdf |
| private://webform/applicant_details/154/india_asia_population_huge.pdf   |
```

#### Sample data script

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `demo`;
CREATE TABLE `demo` (
  `uri` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'The S3 URI of the file.',
  `filesize` bigint unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'The size of the file in bytes.',
  `timestamp` int unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'UNIX timestamp for when the file was added.',
  `dir` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Boolean indicating whether or not this object is a directory.',
  `version` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'The S3 VersionId of the object.'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

INSERT INTO `demo` (`uri`, `filesize`, `timestamp`, `dir`, `version`) VALUES
('private://webform/applicant_details/152/offers   upload  winners .png', 14976905, 1658397516, 0, ''),
('private://webform/applicant_details/153/student : class & teacher data.pdf', 0, 1659525447, 1, ''),
('private://webform/applicant_details/153/tax---user\'s---data__upload.pdf', 98449, 1658397516, 0, ''),
('private://webform/applicant_details/154/Applicant Details _ report_0_2.pdf', 0, 1659525447, 1, ''),
('private://webform/applicant_details/154/india&asia%population  huge.pdf', 13301, 1658397517, 0, '');
```

#### Big Thanks:

**MySQL:** [SELECT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html), [UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html), [REPLACE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replace.html), [SUBSTRING_INDEX](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index), [LOWER](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_lower), [REGEXP_REPLACE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-replace)

**MySQL Query Formatter:** Thanks to [CodeBeautify](https://codebeautify.org/sqlformatter) for such an awesome tool.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE schools SET
slug = lower(name),
slug = REPLACE(slug, '|', ' '),
slug = replace(slug, '.', ' '),
slug = replace(slug, '"', ' '),
slug = replace(slug, '@', ' '),
slug = replace(slug, ',', ' '),
slug = replace(slug, '\'', ''),
slug = trim(slug),
slug = replace(slug, ' ', '-'),
slug = replace(slug, '--', '-');
```

UPDATE schools SET
slug = replace(slug, '--', '-');