# How do i replace multiple keys in mysql

Tags: mysql, string, replace

i would like to replace multiple words from a field in mysql table. I have been doing it using multiple steps:

```
update table1 set fld1=replace(fld1,'and', '');
update table1 set fld1=replace(fld1,'or', '');
update table1 set fld1=replace(fld1,'xor', '');
...
```

How do i do it single step?

Comment: possible duplicates of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1671040/can-mysql-replace-multiple-characters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ugly way...

```
UPDATE table1 SET fld1 = replace(replace(replace(fld1, 'and', ''), 'xor', ''), 'or', '')
```

Note that if you replace 'or' before 'xor' it will match part of 'xor' and leave the x, so the order is important.

Comment: Fool proof would be to surround words with spaces `replace(fld1, ' or ' , ' ')` so that you won't match _oral_ and _orb_

Comment: @KoolKabin I don't know any better way. :D

Answer (score 1):

You can compose `replace` calls:

```
update table1
set fld1 = replace(replace(replace(fld1, 'xor', ''), 'or', ''), 'and', '');
```

I think that's the best you can do in MySQL without compiling in extra user-defined functions. PostgreSQL and (AFAIK) Oracle have full regex support but MySQL only supports regex matching.

If you have to do a lot of this sort of thing then you might want to do it outside the database to get a reasonable solution that doesn't involve insane levels of nested `replace` functions.