# MySQL sorting with symbols as first letter

Tags: mysql, sorting

I have a MySQL table with these rows:

```
¡Hola!
¿Qué tal?
Fine
Hello
Adiós
How are you?
```

How can I sort them to obtain this result:

```
Adiós
Fine
Hello
¡Hola!
How are you?
¿Qué tal?
```

I want MySQL to ignore non alphanumeric characters.
It's possible to do this fast without making a new column with a simplified value?

Comment: What sort order do you want after removing symbols? English? Spanish? Another?

Comment: I'm using UTF8 spanish collation

Comment: Characters like ñ Ñ Á é ü  could appear

Answer (score 0):

It's a notorious pain in the neck to do this in MySQL, unfortunately.

See [Can MySQL replace multiple characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1671040/can-mysql-replace-multiple-characters)

Try this:

```
ORDER BY replace(replace(phrase,'¿',''),'¡','')
```

to remove the Spanish-language prefix punctuation from your phrases as they are sorted. One wishes MySQL had a REGEXP_REPLACE function.

As for the performance, you should be fine with ORDER BY functions unless you have zillions of phrases.  Dozens, no problem.

Comment: I have around 30.000 phrases (movie titles) and my server must handle peaks of 100+ requests per second. I believe that the best approach is to make a new column with the symbols stripped.

Comment: I agree, if you're working at that scale.  But you might want to look into full-text indexing.