# SQL order by products that punctuation mark at the end

Tags: mysql, sql, database

We got a database of products, we need  to order them by name (A-Z) but if the product name begins with a punctuation mark (e.g. ¡A tapear! or ¡Adelgaza!) it should appear near the end and not at the beginning. Is there any way to issue such a query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you simply want to push the A-Z's to the front, and let everything else sort naturally, then use this:

```
ORDER BY case when PRODUCT_NAME like '[a-Z]%' then 1 else 2 end, PRODUCT_NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can extract a list of the punctuation marks you need to ignore, you can actually change the values MySQL sorts by with a statement like:

```
ORDER BY REPLACE(product_name, "¡", "")
```

You can nest several REPLACE() as many times you need.

This has been asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12141475/mysql-sorting-with-symbols-as-first-letter).

Comment: Ok, I don`t want to ignore them, but i guess i can replace those symbols for a value greater than Z

Comment: Yes, using a function on your data should cause MySQL to ignore your indexes.  If possible, precompute, store, and index the "clean" value (or maybe just the first 10 characters, etc).