# ignore dots and commas while making like query in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql-like

I have to do a fuzzy kind of match in a column in mysql I have a column which has fields like this

```
column_name
-----------
A.P Name1
Name2, allias
NAME1
Name2
```

For case insensitivity I have done this

```
select coulmn_name from table where column_name like 'name' COLLATE UTF8_GENERAL_CI;
```

I would like to provide a search box where a user can type `ap` and my query would produce `A.P Name1` as the output from the table. How can I ignore `. & ,` in mysql like statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `REPLACE`function of mysql

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1671040/can-mysql-replace-multiple-characters) to to understand this better.