# Replacing multiple characters in a CASE statement, SQL

Tags: sql, management-studio-express

I would like to change a bunch of characters in a column using a CASE statement in SQL. 
The code is the following

```
CASE
     WHEN [EmpName] LIKE '%æ%' 
       THEN REPLACE([EmpName], 'æ', 'ae')

     WHEN [EmpName] LIKE '%ø%'
       THEN REPLACE([EmpName], 'ø', 'oe') 

     WHEN [EmpName] LIKE '%å%'
       THEN REPLACE([EmpName], 'å', 'aa')

     WHEN [EmpName] LIKE '%-%'
       THEN REPLACE([EmpName], '-', '')

     ELSE [EmpName]
END [EmpName (no special characters)]
```

The problem is that if a name has multiple characters of a different kind (e.g. ø and å), it will only replace only one of them (the first one in the case statement that is ø).
Is there any way to replace every listed character in the CASE statement in one go?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you using MySQL, Oracle or MS SQL Server? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: Skip the case expression, nested replace will to the trick.

Comment: I can use any of them that's why I did it :)
It worked btw!
Thank you so much!!!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can MySQL replace multiple characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1671040/can-mysql-replace-multiple-characters)

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Tag your questions with the database you are really using.

Comment: I'll be more careful next time :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case the `CASE-WHEN` construct is unnecessary. You just need a mass `REPLACE`, which looks like this:

```
REPLACE(
  REPLACE(
    REPLACE(
      REPLACE([EmpName], 'æ', 'ae'),
    'ø', 'oe'),
  'å', 'aa'),
'-', '')
```

Unfortunately, the replacement strings have different size than the original. So you can not use [`TRANSLATE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/translate-transact-sql) here.