# Sanitize During MySQL Insert

Tags: mysql

I'm currently doing a MySQL insert like this:

```
INSERT INTO RESI (MarketingRemarks) 
SELECT PropertyInformation FROM `property_res`;
```

I then run independant commands to clean the RESI table of any strange characters like this:

```
UPDATE RESI SET MarketingRemarks = REPLACE(MarketingRemarks, '“', '"');
UPDATE RESI SET MarketingRemarks = REPLACE(MarketingRemarks, '”', '"');
UPDATE RESI SET MarketingRemarks = REPLACE(MarketingRemarks, '–', '-');
UPDATE RESI SET MarketingRemarks = REPLACE(MarketingRemarks, '½', '1/2');
UPDATE RESI SET MarketingRemarks = REPLACE(MarketingRemarks, '’', '\'');
```

This seems very inefficient to have all these queries.  Is there a way to combine this into a single INSERT statement?

I've tried numerous ways to place the REPLACE into the INSERT statement but with no luck.

Comment: answered before. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1671040/can-mysql-replace-multiple-characters

Comment: @Arquillian I see no INSERT statement here.  That is not a valid answer.

Comment: you can use the replace in your insert at the select place.

Comment: SELECT REPLACE('test', 't', 'v') FROM DUAL;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `replace` function in your `select` clause, like this:

```
INSERT INTO RESI (MarketingRemarks) 
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(PropertyInformation, '½', '1/2'), '“', '"') FROM `property_res`;
```

and you need to build chain of your `replace` function like in example provided by @Arquillian

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to create a function that sanitize the string, and use the function from the insert into command.  You'll have an easy readable code.

```
DELIMITER $$
USE `nestor_dbo`$$
CREATE FUNCTION `Sanitize` (src NVARCHAR(100))
RETURNS NVARCHAR(100)
BEGIN
    DECLARE result NVARCHAR(100);

    SET result = src;

    SET result = replace(result, '“', '"');
    SET result = replace(result, '”', '"');
    SET result = replace(result, '–', '-');
    SET result = replace(result, '½', '1/2');
    SET result = replace(result, '’', '\'');

RETURN result;
END$$


INSERT INTO RESI (MarketingRemarks) 
SELECT Sanitize(PropertyInformation) FROM `property_res`;
```