# MySQL Select and Remove JSON Characters from a Column

Tags: mysql, json, regex, trim

I have a mysql db that contains a column `tagids`, it contains the following rows;

```
["7"]
["4"]
["6"]
["7"]
["1"]
["6"]
```

The data is JSON format, and each values is stored in a seperate row.

I need to select the integers only from this column, i.e remove the `["` and `"]`

I'd like my output to be;

```
7
4
6
7
1
6
```

I have tried the trim function but can;t see to get it working.

```
SELECT TRIM( '[""]' FROM tagids) from mytable
```

How can I achieve this? DO I need to use regex?

Comment: Why not `REPLACE` the `["` and `"]` with empty string?

Comment: Could you please provide an example @WiktorStribiżew, thanks!

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1671056/3832970) it is.